# Why isn't NPM updating?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've scoured SO to find the answer. Everytime I try to update npm, it seems like it updates from current version (6.14.11), but when I check the version, I've still got the old one instead of 7.6.3 (the current version). I'm almost certain it has to do with the path, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I've cleared the cache, tried other commands, but nothing's working. This is a problem, as I'm trying to install Sass from the command line using `gem install sass` (again, seems like it works until I `sass -v` and it says `command not found`. Just seems like until I get npm to update, nothing's gonna work. Thanks in advance:

```
MacBook-Pro-3:~ saige$ npm install -g npm
/Users/saige/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /Users/saige/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
/Users/saige/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /Users/saige/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@7.6.3
updated 253 packages in 5.035s
MacBook-Pro-3:~ saige$ npm -v
6.14.11
```

Comment: It means you have 2 copies of NPM installed, and the other one has priority in your `$PATH`

Comment: Brilliant. How does one go about correcting that path? I've tried doing a couple of things (deleting old NPM installs) and now I'm getting strange errors 'EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/usr/local/bin/npm' - any ideas? Thanks a ton for your help.